# Smaller radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, power-series

Suppose we have two power series, with coefficients $a_n, b_n$, both with radius of convergence, $R$. 
Let the power series with the coefficients $a_n+b_n$, with radius $R'$

I need an example for scenario where $R'<R$. The other cases are easy NY the way.

Written from mobile. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no example, since $R' \ge R$ holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The power series with coefficients $a_n + b_n$ is the sum of the first two, which have coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$. What can you say about the sum of those two series at a point where both of them are convergent?